# Are there names/terms of Hold'em above the level of hands?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Are there names/terms for the sequence of cards **other than** positions, holds, and hands?  For instance I once at a private game the first deal when I sat down was:

- Big Blind - AA
- Little Blind - KK
- me Under the gun, with AK.

Comment: Question seems confusing to me. The only names / terms i know is what @Grinch91 posted as links, specific hands and positions. What are these _sequences_ are you talking about?

Comment: @vlzvl IDK what the proper term would be for the sequences.  Not knowing that either, I included an example of what I am asking about.  Three people sitting next to each other get dealt AA, KK, and AK.  There are no terms for such things?

Comment: as far as i know there's no such terms, but i may be wrong as well. Never heard any, probably because there's no reason? KK vs AA, one of them busted, never heard any _term_ for this encounter :)

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure if you are looking for specific hand nicknames or names of the positions at the table.

For hand nicknames check [this](http://www.badbeatpokershirts.com/pokerhandnicknames.htm) out.

For table positions check [this](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/positions-in-poker) out.

Hope this clears things up. If not let me know what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I updated by question a bit.  I'm looking for terms other than those for hands, positions, or holds.  Things like sequences of holds dealt to players.  Such as the the sequence I used for my example.

Answer (score 2):

If I am to understand your question correctly.

You're not looking for names of hands IE Rockets, Big Slick, The Doyle Brunson.

You're not looking for names of positions like BB, SB, Under the Gun, Hero Villian etc.

You're wanting to see if there are terms for a specific series of cards dealt to all players in the hand.  So a name for the hand as a whole for all player rather than for the individual (AA vs KK vs AK).

I do not believe any terms are around for what you're looking for as there would be so many possible combinations, tho I could see some humor for some of the more famous ones like the one above or the WSOP flopped four of a kind vs full house hand 1.

Comment: Yes!  With so many combinations I suspected there wouldn't be, but some seem name worthy, though maybe they don't occur often enough to be worth referencing by a term.

Comment: I agree that while some situations like the one you described are interesting, they don't happen frequently enough to receive attention. (That being said, I was once the KK holder in the three way scenario you posed, though the positions were different. AK was not happy to see he was drawing nearly dead, and I was not happy to see I had only 1 out.)